# asyncio.run fails when loop.run_until_complete works

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-3.7, motor-asyncio

This code fails:

```
import asyncio
from motor import motor_asyncio


_client = motor_asyncio.AsyncIOMotorClient()
_db = _client.db

users = _db.users


async def main():
    await users.create_index(
        'login',
        unique=True
    )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    #loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    #loop.run_until_complete(main())
    asyncio.run(main())
```

With this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sanyash/myrepos/TKP/db.py", line 21, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/asyncio/runners.py", line 43, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 584, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/home/sanyash/myrepos/TKP/db.py", line 14, in main
    unique=True
RuntimeError: Task <Task pending coro=<main() running at /home/sanyash/myrepos/TKP/db.py:14> cb=[_run_until_complete_cb() at /usr/local/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py:158]> got Future <Future pending cb=[run_on_executor.<locals>._call_check_cancel() at /usr/local/lib/python3.7/motor/frameworks/asyncio/__init__.py:80]> attached to a different loop
```

When I uncomment two lines with `loop` and comment `asyncio.run` it works well. What the matter? I thought `asyncio.run` is a shortcut for this two lines.

The problem is something in the `motor_asyncio` implementation, because when I changed `main` to simple `return 42`, `asyncio.run` works well too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What the matter? I thought `asyncio.run` is a shortcut for this two
>   lines.

No, it does much more. In particular it [creates and sets](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3396d1e0ca858065c5bb7e5a9737be6ffc4028f7/Lib/asyncio/runners.py#L39) an new event loop. And this is why you get error: `AsyncIOMotorClient()` creates some async stuff for default event loop, but another loop created by `asyncio.run` tries to use it.

If you want to preserve `asyncio.run` you should move init stuff inside `main()`:

```
# ...

_client = None
_db = None
users = None


async def main():
    global _client, _db, users
    _client = motor_asyncio.AsyncIOMotorClient()
    _db = _client.db
    users = _db.users

    # ...
```

It's a good idea in general to start things when event loop is already set and running instead of doing something at module-level.